# Linking folder security to AD security groups Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ntfs

I am trying to write a script which links a folder's security permissions to an existing AD group. I've yet to find any script or cmdlet (Set-Acl can't link to groups, only explicit permissions) which allows me to script this.

As an example, I have a folder called "FOLDER A" and an AD security group called "FOLDER A". Is there any way for add the AD group to the folder's security?

**AD group within folder permissions example:**

[image: AD group within folder permissions example]

**EDIT:** I may have found a solution on serverfault. I can use the Get-ADGroup cmdlet to find the SID of each group and then pass the IdentityReference for the Set-Acl. Will test this out and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Hey, its good that you found an answer to your question. When you tested it, feel free to write an answer to your question where you explain what you did. Take a look here first ;) : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I always use the [NTFSSecurity](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity) module when dealing with filesystem permissions. The commands in this module are much easier to understand than `Set-Acl` as they act in the same way the GUI does.

To add permissions to a folder it's just one command:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path 'C:\Folder A' -Account 'Domain\Folder A' -AccessRights Read
```

It's worth reading the documentation links as the module can do way more than just adding permissions!

Note: You do need to install the module, if you're using a modern version of Powershell this is easy as you can just use `Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity`. If it's an older version you will need download and install the module manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to my problem. Thank you to James C. - whilst I couldn't figure it out using your method, I believe it did point me in the right direction.

I essentially used the `FileSystemAccessRule`constructor. The moment of clarity I had was the realisation that I could actually reference AD groups. I'm very new to Powershell so this wasn't immediately obvious to me. Here's the implementation:

```
$acl = Get-Acl <PATH OF FOLDER>

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('<NAME OF GROUP>','<PERMISSIONS>,'<Allow/Deny>')

$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl <PATH OF FOLDER>
```

The full documentation of the constructor can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2). I then used a Python script to format all the data in a csv and loop through it to create the groups.

Thanks everyone!